# Save and read multiple layers of lists to csv in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm fairly new to working with csv-files and have some trouble when I save and read lists to/from a file. I know how to save/read a list of lists as csv, however I want to save/read a list with multiple layers of lists inside and can't figure out how that is done.

Have looked at other related questions, but they all regard how to save/read list of lists and not list of more layers than 2. So hope someone can help.

The list looks like this:

```
[
 [['Text 1', 'Text 2'],           0],
 [['Text 3'],                     1],
 [['Text 4', 'Text 5', 'Text 6'], 2]
]
```

When I just use a regular save and read code as:

```
with open(path, 'w', newline='\n') as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     writer.writerows(my_list)

with open(path, newline='') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     my_list = list(reader)
```

The output becomes:

```
[
 ["['Text 1', 'Text 2']", 0],
 ["['Text 3']",           1],
 ["['Text 4', 'Text 5']", 2]
]
```

i.e. only a list of list and not a list of more layers than 2 as it originally was.

So is there any way to set multiple layers of the list when saving/reading to a csv file? Or is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: do you necessarly need to use .csv files, if not you can save your list of lists as a .pkl pickle  (in case you do not wish to display it outside your code) file

Comment: You're right, I do not necessarily need to save it as a csv-file, so I will look into .pkl. thanks

Comment: [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) might be a better idea.